# Combinations of all charcaters and all lengths with using less number of loops?

Tags: tcl, brute-force

Brain Teaser: I self originated this question, but stuck completely.

I want to create all possible combination of all characters, but of all possible lengths. Suppose, [a-z] combination of 1 length, then [a-z] combination of 2 length, and so on till the maximum length achieved.

this could be very easily done by iterative looping.

Example for 3 length:

```
proc triples list {
    foreach i $list {
        foreach j $list {
            foreach k $list {
                puts [list $i $j $k]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, it should solve using less loops (looping needs to be dynamic)

```
set chars "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set chars [split $chars ""]

set complete_length [llength $chars]

set start 0
set maximum_length 15


while {1} {
    if {$start > $maximum_length} {
        break
    }
    for {set i [expr $maximum_length-$start]} {$i >= 0} {incr i -1} {
        # dump combinations
    }
    incr start
}
```

In this chunk, what algorithm or method i should apply? Any kind of suggestions/help/code will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, your `for` loop will break every time until the `while` loop breaks, since at the start `set i` will be `15`, which makes `$i < 0` false.

Comment: You probably want something like http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations or http://wiki.tcl.tk/2553

Comment: thanks @glennjackman, i will understand them and will revert back to you..

Comment: You are aware that 26**15 = 1677259342285725925376? (16e20, or “wow, that's a lot!”) Current builds of Tcl won't make a list with nearly that many elements…

Comment: @DonalFellows, not looking for that much... just printing.. or lets just looking out for logic... Not a task.. just logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry, this is not an answer, but hopefully some interesting discussion anyway:

The word "combinations" is often used way too generally, so it can be interpreted in many different ways. Let's say that you have a source list of 26 different elements, the english letters, and you want to **pick** 3 of them and **combine** in a 3 element destination list:

- Can you always pick any letter from the source list, or do the elements disappear from it as you pick them? Either define "pick" (are the elements copied or moved during a pick), or define the set of source values (is there 1 of each of A-Z or an infinite amount of A-Z).
- Does the order in the destination list matter? Is `AHM` considered to be the same combination as `HAM`? Define "combine".
- If you have a list where not all elements are different, e.g. {2 10 10 64 100}, you have even more possibilities. Define your set of values.

Your first example prints [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), not [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). If that's what you want, the easiset way is a recursive procedure. Combinations are more complicated to generate.

**EDIT:**

I wrote this procedure for a Project Euler program. It picks all the elements, but maybe you can modify it to pick n. It takes a command prefix as argument, so you don't have to store all permutations.

```
package require Tcl 8.5.0

proc forEachPerm {list cmdPrefix} {
  _forEachPerm {} $list $cmdPrefix
}

proc _forEachPerm {head list cmdPrefix} {
  if {![llength $list]} {
    {*}$cmdPrefix $head
  } else {
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list]} {incr i} {
      _forEachPerm [concat $head [lrange $list $i $i]] [lreplace $list $i $i] $cmdPrefix
    }
  }
}

# example use:
forEachPerm {a b c} {apply {{list} {puts [join $list]}}}
```